# Exclude data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query that returns data and coordinates for an amount of routes. When the amount of coordinates exceeds a specific value I would like to exclude coordinates for the following routes.

This is my method where I try to do this, the problem is when I try to seralize the object, JSON.net serialize times out.

```
    public static object returnFullSelectWithCoordinates(IQueryable<RouteQueryModel> r)
    {
        int totalCoordinateCount = 0;
        foreach (route x in r.Select(c => c.b))
        {
            if (totalCoordinateCount > DataValues.AmountOfCoordinates)
            {
                x.coordinates.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                totalCoordinateCount += x.coordinates.Count;
                if (totalCoordinateCount > DataValues.AmountOfCoordinates)
                {
                    x.coordinates.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        return r.Select(b => new
        {
            route_id = b.b.route_id,
            name = b.b.name,
            description = b.b.description,
            distance = b.b.distance,
            distance_to_route = (int)b.distance_to_from_me,
            departure_place = b.b.departure_place,
            arrival_place = b.b.arrival_place,
            owner = b.b.user.username,
            average_rating = b.avg_rating,
            is_favorite = b.is_favorite,
            date = b.b.date,
            attributes = b.b.route_attributes.Select(c => c.route_attribute_types.attribute_name),
            coordinates = b.b.coordinates.Select(c => new coordinateToSend { sequence = c.sequence, lat = c.position.Latitude, lon = c.position.Longitude })
        });
    }
```

Comment: You are using an anonymous type and returning an object which could potentially cause some problems. Consider another model, then returning `IEnumerable<Model>` instead of an `Anonymous object`.

Comment: What do you mean 'times out' ?

Comment: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Comment: You have 2 `r.Select(`, i.e. possible multiple evaluation of query. Try to save it once like `r.ToArray()` and then use the array.

Comment: As an SQL exception? It sounds like your DB is taking too long to execute the query - nothing to do with JSon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by  Vladimir Frolov you enumerate over the results twice. That is a waste of time and resources but the worst thing is that the second time you start all over and the changes of the first iteration are lost.

So I would turn it around: first fetch the data you need, so you can benefit from the projection that narrows down the SQL query. Then change whatever needs to be changed:

```
public static object returnFullSelectWithCoordinates(IQueryable<RouteQueryModel> r)
{
    var results = r.Select(b => new
    {
        route_id = b.b.route_id,
        name = b.b.name,
        description = b.b.description,
        distance = b.b.distance,
        distance_to_route = (int)b.distance_to_from_me,
        departure_place = b.b.departure_place,
        arrival_place = b.b.arrival_place,
        owner = b.b.user.username,
        average_rating = b.avg_rating,
        is_favorite = b.is_favorite,
        date = b.b.date,
        attributes = b.b.route_attributes
                     .Select(c => c.route_attribute_types.attribute_name),
        coordinates = b.b.coordinates.Select(c => new coordinateToSend 
                                                  { sequence = c.sequence,
                                                    lat = c.position.Latitude, 
                                                    lon = c.position.Longitude
                                                  })
    }).ToList(); // ToList !!

    int totalCoordinateCount = 0;
    foreach (var x in results)
    {
        if (totalCoordinateCount + x.coordinates.Count
                                 > DataValues.AmountOfCoordinates)
        {
            x.coordinates.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            totalCoordinateCount += x.coordinates.Count;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```